# Update/insert/delete child records in database

Tags: sqlite, one-to-many, updates

Consider a classic sales order saved in a database in two tables:

```
SALE_ORDER                   SALE_ORDER_ITEM
----------                   ---------------
id       integer             ...
...                           order_id        integer references sale_order (id)
                              item_id         integer references item (id)
                              quantity        integer
                              ...
```

For the purpose of this question, ignore item_id reference to another table - it's irrelevant.

I have a class that encompasses an order, something like:

```
public class SaleOrder {
    private int orderId;
    ...
    private List<BoughtItem> items;
    ....
}
```

An order can change (my requirements), and changes can include items in the list: items added, removed or quantity changed.  When I update this order in the database, the obvious easiest thing to do is to `delete from sale_order_item where order_id=<my_order_id>` and then insert rows going through the list.  This however seems quite inefficient to me, especially considering that the list can contains (potentially) hundreds of different items. (Background: these are orders from supermarkets to wholesale product suppliers.)

The alternative would be to query the database and then compare the list with the cursor, adding, deleting or updating where necessary - which seems at least just as inefficient.

1. Is there another (third?) approach that is more efficient?
2. If not, which one of the two is better?  I always used the first one (delete all, then reinsert, however now started doubting myself.

**Update:** the database is sqlite3 (on android if that matters)

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Quassnoi oops, forgot to include that info. It's sqlite on android.

Comment: I'd love to know what the downvote was for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a PK on sale_order_item if you don't have it already.

Keep a dirty buffer that you can replay when updating the database. So if the user changes an item, add an entry 'update sale_order_item set item_id = "1234" where sale_order_item.id = "2222"'.

Then when it comes to communicating with the database, play back those changes. It doesn't matter how you record the changes (recording the SQL isn't the most efficient). The key is being able to recognize what's changed in each item, or addition/removal of items, and then being able to create the sql based on that.

I hope it gives you an idea.

Comment: A big problem with this is that it breaks separation of functionality.  Right now I have my `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass class, which has method `updateOrder(SaleOrder order)`.  Per your answer, I would have to create SQL statements in `SaleOrder` class, which isn't particularly nice.  Of course, I can keep track of the changes in another way, but how efficient is it? Especially memory efficiency against speed.  Remember, the app is to run on a mobile device, so should minimise memory footprint.

Comment: Why can't SaleOrder maintain 1) whether or not it is dirty and 2) if dirty, the specific changes that were made? Pay now or pay later...

Comment: Eventually, I developed this idea and worked around the functionality separation.  `Order` keeps track of 'added', 'removed' and 'updated' items; them database access class gets the lists of these items and updates from there.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on whether you'll be updating the items or just re-inserting them. If you don't need to do any updates, a delete + insert will be fine if you add existing items to the clause (so you don't delete things that are in the new list)

if the new list is always golden, then there's no point in using a cursor because you already have your data, so just stick with the delete/re-insert - its not as inefficient as a cursor would be.

e.g. t-sql

```
insert into sale_order_item(columns..)
select field1, 2, etc. from your_new_list a 
where not exists (select 1 from sale_order_item where item_id = a.item_id)
```

Comment: I'm using sqlite on android, so the syntax is different.  The new list is golden, so deleting/reinserting will give correct data at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the original list of item IDs, you must delete at least all those items that are not anymore in your list:

```
DELETE FROM sale_order_item
WHERE order_id = ?
  AND item_id NOT IN (id1, id2, ...)
```

You cannot avoid updating records if you don't know if they have changed or not.

However, it is possible to avoid inserting records that already exist:
If you have a proper primary key on the (order_id, item_id) columns, you can use the [`INSERT OR REPLACE` command](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

However, all this is no more efficient that just the simple `DELETE` and the `INSERT`s.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add field recordState : enum {rfNone, rfInserted, rfUpdated, rdDeleted}.
2. Add appropriate code to all your setter methods, something like

   ```
   public void setData(String value) {
       if (!this.data.equals(value)) {
           this.data = value;
           if (getRecordState() == rfNone)
               setRecordState(rfUpdated);
       }    
   }
   ```

   This code will ensure you to mark record object as updated if any value of the record class has changed, if of course this object in not newly constructed
3. All record read from database must be initialy : recordState = rfNone
4. Newly added record must be marked : recordState = rfInserted at creation
5. Deleted records must be marked: recordState = rfDeleted (do not delete them instantly)
6. At the end traverse list of record objects and make appropriate actions based on recordState value